# render audio in realtime in Watch OS

Tags: watchos

Is it possible to render PCM audio in realtime to the speaker/headphones/active audio route on the Apple Watch? In iOS, this is possible through AudioUnits using AudioToolbox. In Watch OS, the closest thing seems to be AVAudioEngine and it's manual render mode, but the documentation is confusing and suggests manual render mode is disconnected from an output source. Any advice on rendering audio bytes on realtime on Watch OS would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this starting WatchOS 6.0+ and the new AVAudioSourceNode. See Apple Documentation here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosourcenode

As of this writing AVAudioSourceNode is in beta.